# Removing the padding in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, padding

I have horizontal recyclerview with cardview root layout and it has huge padding

[image]

the cardview is supposed to end at the end of textview

here is the XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/main_category_name"
    android:id="@+id/mainCategoryName"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is the second file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ShoppingPackage.MainShoppingActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainCategoriesRecyclerView"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainCategoriesRecyclerView"
    android:id="@+id/subCategoriesRecyclerView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to remove `hint` I don't know why but hint seems to give padding, so I used `text` and I didn't have padding anymore